# Creating a dynamic stream from two or more similar looking java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I wrote the following code using Java streams.

```
@Data
public class Car {

    private Long carId;
    private Long carNumber;
    private Long carColorId;
    private String engineNumber;
    private String partsNumber;
    private String modifiedBy;
    
}

List<Car> carList = List.of(new Car(1L, 100L, 1000L, "1ACB", "ZEGV200", "John"), new Car(2L, 100L, 1000L, "1TUV", "ZVAV200", "Doe"), new Car(3L, 200L, 2000L, "1ZVC", "CADV200", "Jane"), new Car(4L, 200L, 2000L, "8CEB", "V2IWD00", "Harry"));

carList.stream().filter(x -> !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(x.getCarNumber()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Car::getCarNumber, Function.identity(),
                (x1, x2) -> new Car(x1.getCarNumber(),
                        x1.getEngineNumber().concat(x2.getEngineNumber()))));


carList.stream().filter(x -> !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(x.getCarColorId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Car::getCarColorId, Function.identity(),
                (x1, x2) -> new Car(x1.getCarColorId(),
                        x1.getEngineNumber().concat(x2.getEngineNumber()))));
```

The above streams are pretty much the same except for the key in the map and the filter condition. I would like to know if I can create a single stream that can accommodate both the streams listed above and called `based on input condition`.

For example: if I pass a string colorId then the stream with condition colorId would be called in the dynamic stream.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am not sure I am understanding it right. Can you please elaborate it with a piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is to pass a lambda expression that tells your algorithm which property to use from the Car object:

```
static <T> Map<T, Car> collectCars(List<Car> carList, Function<Car, T> keyMapper) {
    return carList.stream()
            .filter(x -> !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(keyMapper.apply(x)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    keyMapper,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (x1, x2) -> new Car(
                            x1.getCarColorId(),
                            x1.getEngineNumber().concat(x2.getEngineNumber()))
            ));
}
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```
@Test
void test() {
    Map<Long, Car> carsByColorId = collectCars(carList, Car::getCarColorId);
    Map<Long, Car> carsByCarNumber = collectCars(carList, Car::getCarNumber);
    Map<String, Car> carsByEngine = collectCars(carList, Car::getEngineNumber);

    System.out.println(carsByEngine);
}
```

and you can dynamically decide which `getter` to pas as an argument based on your inputs. This is also known as the "strategy pattern" you can read more about it here: https://medium.com/javarevisited/venkats-lightweight-strategy-pattern-using-lambda-expressions-626c04654b18?sk=e01874f8b8d780a70c73d7bd8a32add8

Answer (score 0):

As you said, when you input **carNumber**, then the map key is carNumber, when you input **carColorId**, then the map key is carColorId.

So you can try code below with **Method reference**:

1. Firstly, you can create **filter** method to cumstom your Predicate, create **getIdentity** method as keyMapper, and the method **mergeFunction** for resolve
   collisions.

```java
public class Car {
    // property, getter and setter ...
    public boolean filter() {
        return !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(this.getCarNumber()) && !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(this.getCarColorId());
    }
    
    public static Long getIdentity(Car car) {
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(car.getCarNumber())) {
            return car.getCarNumber();
        } else {
            return car.getCarColorId();
        }
    }
    
    public static Car mergeFunction(Car car1, Car car2) {
        // do merge
        return car1;
    }
}
```

2. then you can use it in stream

```java
Map<Long, Car> collect = carList.stream().filter(Car::filter)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Car::getIdentity, Function.identity(), Car::mergeFunction));
```

Help it works for you.